# Erro Laravel Database name seems incorrect como resolver?

Tags: banco-de-dados, laravel, laravel-eloquent, packages, schema

Recentemente criei um service provider, que de certa forma funciona.
porem quando vou capturar os dados do banco usando `Produtos::all();` recebo o seguinte erro:

> Database name seems incorrect You're using the default database name
>   laravel. This database does not exist.
>
> Edit the .env file and use the correct database name in the
>   DB_DATABASE key.

os dados no arquivo ENV:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=tommy.heliohost.org
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=ricmlima_site
DB_USERNAME=ricmlima
DB_PASSWORD=*******
```

/config/database.php

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'), 
'connections' => [ 'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'prefix_indexes' => true,
    'strict' => true,
    'engine' => null,
    'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
         PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
    ]) : [],  
],
```

EU ja tentei remover os dados padroes no arquivo /config/database.php

```
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'tommy.heliohost.org'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'ricmlima_site'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'ricmlima'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', '********'),
```

Porem não resolveu.
o que faço ?

Comment: Já tentou trocar o host para `localhost` invés de `tommy.heliohost.org` ? Como a aplicação está hospedada nesse servidor provavelmente vai funcionar assim.

Comment: :D Eu estou com a aplicação rodando localmente. com banco de dados externo. @LaércioLopes . Porem eu  acabei de resolver. Refazendo o cache do laravel. Muitissimo obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solução para esse problema foi refazer o cache do laravel:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

imediatamente ficou perfeito.

Comment: Curiosamente, php artisan optimize:clear não limpou as configurações, mas php artisan config:cache, sim!